# Jira REST API keep giving me bad request in C#

Tags: c#, jira-rest-api

Here is my code in c# which gives me bad request error

```
string data = @"{""fields"":{""project"":{""key"": ""md""},""summary"": ""reset example"",""description"": ""creating an issue via rest api"",""issuetype"": {""name"": ""bug""}}}"; 
//string postUrl = "https://aconline.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/";
string postUrl = "https://aconline.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue";
System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(postUrl);
byte[] cred = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("username:password");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(cred));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
//&lt; Issue & gt;
System.Net.Http.HttpContent content = new System.Net.Http.ObjectContent<string>(data, jsonFormatter);
//var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("issue", content).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    //descrptiontextBox.Text = result;
    ViewData["Result"] = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
else
{
    //descrptiontextBox.Text = response.StatusCode.ToString();
    ViewData["Result"] = response.StatusCode.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error response?

Comment: But what's in the body of the response? This is too vague.

Comment: StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request'

Comment: This will be hard to answer unless someone is very familiar with the jira API. Consult the documentation and compare the spec with what you are sending in the request.

Comment: Know it is bad practice to block on async calls with `.Result` and to new up an `HttpClient` for each request.

Comment: @khushbutrivedi Run `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` in your else block and see if there's anything in the body that might be a hint as to what might be wrong with your request.

Comment: Instead of `Task.Result`, try to use `async/await`.
example:
instead of `ViewData["Result"] = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;` , 
you can use `ViewData["Result"] = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` and add `async` modifier and proper rerun type to the method.
(Even though this may not related to original question. I thought worth mentioning it.)

Comment: Try using `https://aconline.atlassian.net` as the base URL  and then call PostAsync with `/rest/api/2/issue`.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange hey thanks, when i tried that i got this {"errorMessages":["Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.atlassian.jira.rest.v2.issue.IssueUpdateBean] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method"]}   i dont know what does this means i am trying rest api first time i still figuring out what does this mean

Comment: instead of `ObjectContent`, try `StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");`

Comment: Hey @Crowcoder   when i tried StringContent it gave me this {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"project":"project is required"}}

Comment: Thank you to all  for your help , Its working now I have changed  ObjectContent to StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); and than i had to change my string a bit as it is case sensitive and worked thanks @Crowcoder